# Changing header style in Report

Tags: header-footer, lyx, fancyhdr, report

I am using LyX and I am writing my thesis using the report class (two-sided). I put in Latex preamble the following code:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize  \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize  \leftmark}
```

It produces the right content, however, the text is too big (even though I have `\footnotesize`) and I do not like the style. 
It currently looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to look more like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: The font style in the headers that you seek is called `\scshape` (small caps).

Comment: You need to alter the definition of the marks to avoid the uppercase.

Comment: Did you select `fancy` under Document > Settings... > Page Layout > Page Layout?

Comment: *Last seen May 13 at 19:11* Apparently, there is no interest in having the question answered. If have no idea how the OP managed to get the current output with the smaller *A*s. I vote to close as unclear, since in its current state, it won't any other user.